# Chromium-browser build fatal errors in module_list.cc: Check Failed

Tags: c++, windows, browser, windows-10, chromium

I've been trying to build chromium on Windows 10, but I am getting weird errors on runtime, which appear to be caused by that pattern:

```
void CheckFreeLibrary(HMODULE module) {
  BOOL result = ::FreeLibrary(module);
  DCHECK(result);
}
```

The first errors are displayed after a few seconds after Chromium is started. Here's what it says:

```
[5904:9192:0726/025753:FATAL:module_list.cc(18)] Check failed: result.
Backtrace:
    base:debug:StackTrace:StackTrace [0x0000....] (e:\projects\clones\chromium\src\base\debug\stack_trace.cc) ...
```

Since I couldn't copy paste the whole stack, I will join a screenshot of what it all feels like:
[image: StackTrace errors]

I am successful in building the last revision, or at least, it appears to be successful since no errors are showing up when compiling with the toolchain recommended in [Building instructions](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code#TOC-Building).

Luckily, the first errors aren't modal and it is possible to browse a little bit afterwards. Then, if I put the application into heavy loading (such as Facebook newsfeed), it will suddently stop responding in a silent way. Mouse hovering effects will not show anymore and reloading the page will result in infinite loading. This behavior is also reproductible when right-clicking on some pages (e.g.: google's home page does it sometimes).

What could be an explanation of this not working "out of the box" with default configuration? How to fix this?

P.S.: This question is complementary to this question:
[Windows chromium-browser fresh build stacktrace and anonymous fatal errors on runtime](https://superuser.com/questions/1105560/windows-chromium-browser-fresh-build-stacktrace-and-anonymous-fatal-errors-on-ru/1105572?noredirect=1#comment1573176_1105572), if it can help getting the big picture of the question.

P.S.2.: I am currently trying to rebuild from start again with this slight change to see if it works out better. I will be able to see it after about 10 hours, though (yes, the build is painful on my current setup).

```
void CheckFreeLibrary(HMODULE module) {
  BOOL result = ::FreeLibrary(module);
  if (!result) {
      result = ::UnmapViewOfFile(module);
  }
  DCHECK(result);
}
```

**Update - 2016/07/29**

Test with CheckFreeLibrary still failed in debug, but I finally found a way to resolve the issues in a build. See update 3 in superuser [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1105560/windows-chromium-browser-fresh-build-stacktrace-and-anonymous-fatal-errors-on-ru). What I did was configuring the build into release mode via `gn args`. This is, obviously, almost impossible to debug with, so a solution / explanation is yet to be found about why it fails in debug mode. This is quite close now, though.

**Update 2 - 2016/08/13**

Started all over again to have a debug version again with the latest version in the repositories, and this time I was sure enough to find something. In fact, after I've run through the usual procedure to update, generate and build, I noticed that some `win-core-*` DLL libraries located in the Windows Kit debugger weren't copied `src` folder but one of those was assumed to be there during the link process. As a precaution, I've simply copied them all to be sure that any delay-load or build dependency was there. The first time chromium has launched, the errors didn't show up and thought it was resolving the issue. However, right-clicking on the Google Homepage had the same effect (no response, then browser not showing pages anymore). After closing and reopening it, errors are beginning to show up.

Is there anyone that had experienced that? I would be very happy with something like "do it on linux, it works better on this platform". I am not willing to do it without knowing it will work any better, though.

Answer (score 0):

So

```
BOOL result = ::FreeLibrary(module);
```

fails in debug builds see if you have a

```
DWORD WINAPI GetLastError(void);
```

to get the real error.

I could guess

> module not loaded
>
> module is NULL

Perhaps some DEBUG statement is changing the value of module?